How could I close this navbar by clicking out of it?
`import './SideNavBar.scss';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Cancel01Icon, Menu01Icon } from '../assets/icons';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const SideNavBar = () => {

const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

const toggleMenu = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

   return (
  <>
    <button className="menu-button" onClick={toggleMenu}>

     {isOpen ? <Cancel01Icon className='sideicon' /> : <Menu01Icon className='sideicon' />}

    </button>

  <nav className={`side-navbar ${isOpen ? 'open' : ''}`}>
    <ul className='side-navbar-ul'>
      <li className='side-navbar-li'><Link to={'/'}>Home</Link></li>
        <div className='line'></div>
      <li className='side-navbar-li'><Link to={'/loja'}>Loja</Link></li>
        <div className='line'></div>
      <li className='side-navbar-li'><Link to={'/galeria'}>Galeria</Link></li>
        <div className='line'></div>
      <li className='side-navbar-li'><Link to={'/contato'}>Contato</Link></li>
        <div className='line'></div>
      <li className='side-navbar-li'><a>Restrito</a></li>
        <div className='line'></div>
        
      

         </ul>
       </nav>
     </>

     )};

     export default SideNavBar;`

#How could I make this navbar close when I click in out of it, considering that this is a React app? I've seen somethings but it's more like vanila js, I need to know how to do this in a React component, jsx

You can use this hook that I wrote before:
/**
 * Custom hook that triggers a callback function when a click event occurs outside of a specified element.
 * @param ref - The ref object that represents the element to monitor for click events.
 * @param callback - The callback function will be executed when a click event occurs outside the element.
 * @param disable - Optional parameter to disable the click event handling. Defaults to false.
 */
export function useOnClickOutside(
  ref: RefObject<HTMLElement>,
  callback: () => void,
  disable = false
) {
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleClickOutside(event: MouseEvent): boolean {
      if (disable) return false;
      if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target as Node)) {
        callback();
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    }
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, [ref, callback, disable]);
}


If for some reason you don't want to use this hook, you can take the useEffect part and put it directly in your component
